# Why does Enumerable.ToLookup<>() return an ILookup<,> and not a Lookup<,>?

Tags: .net, api-design, enumerable

There is *one* method in `Lookup<,>` that is not in `ILookup<,>`:

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> ApplyResultSelector<TResult>(
    Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>, TResult> resultSelector);
```

Why is the return type of `Enumerable.ToLookup<>()` declared to be `ILookup<,>` despite the fact that it always seems to return an instance of `Lookup<,>`? If the return type were instead declared to be `Lookup<,>`, the above method could be used without a cast.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best practices for designing public APIs dictate that returning an interface is a better idea than returning a concrete class, because you can then return a different concrete class if you need to. The consumer of the API is not supposed to rely on the returned instance being of a specific type.

As you point out, `ToList` and `ToDictionary` return concrete types rather than interfaces. Perhaps the reason for this is that `ToList` and `ToDictionary` were meant to return you a copy that you can **modify** should you want to. Since the `IList` and `IDictionary` interfaces do not guarantee you that they are editable (which was possibly a bad idea), the designers decided to return the concrete type.

Imagine a hypothetical `ToIList()` method. If called on an array, it could be implemented to return you a copy of the array, because arrays implement `IList<T>`. You might then be surprised to find out that calling `Add()` throws.

On the other hand, `ILookup` is a read-only interface, so the above doesn't apply. Hence there is no reason *not* to follow the best practice, like there is with `ToList`.

Comment: Well then surely `ToList` and `ToDictionary` are really badly designed.